# Magento2 : How to add telephone in order csv export

Tags: magento-2.1.7, export

I want to add customer billing telephone in `Billing Address` column in Order csv export.

Is there any setting in admin to add telephone?

Or need to override any core function for this?

Answer (score 3):

Just tested and work on 2.2.5, you can try on 2.1.7 :)

Create custom module **Custom/Module**

- In **etc/di.xml**

  ```
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
      <virtualType name="Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid">
          <arguments>
              <argument name="columns" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="billing_telephone" xsi:type="string">sales_billing_address.telephone</item>
              </argument>
          </arguments>
      </virtualType>
  </config>
  ```
- Create **InstallSchema/UpgradeSchema** class to add new column

  ```
  <?php

  namespace Custom\Module\Setup;

  use Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;

  class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
  {
      public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {
          $setup->startSetup();

          $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
              $setup->getTable('sales_order_grid'),
              'billing_telephone',
              [
                  'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                  'length' => 255,
                  'comment' => 'Billing Telephone'
              ]
          );

          $setup->endSetup();
      }
  }
  ```
- Create file **Custom/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml**

  ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

   <listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
      <columns name="sales_order_columns">
          <column name="billing_telephone">
              <settings>
                  <filter>text</filter>
                  <label translate="true">Billing Telephone</label>
                  <visible>false</visible>
              </settings>
          </column>
      </columns>
  </listing>
  ```

Comment: I tried it, but it is not working for me.

Comment: Have you tried to place new order? Old placed orders will not show because they missed index to `sales_order_grid` table

Comment: Its working fine for me .. thanks @QuanLe